# Does docker-compose build an image and run a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Does docker-compose do both: build an image and run the container of the built image?

If i run docker-compose up, does it also build containers or only run the container? If it only runs, why is there a **build** command in the .yml like in:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  mycompose:
    build: .
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to answer is to reference the documentation:

"Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration. To learn more about all the features of Compose..."

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/